# Are best linear unbiased predictions (BLUPs) a good indicator of the mean value for that random effect member?

Tags: r, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

I have data on prices of houses in different districts, and would like to determine how expensive different districts are when it comes to buying a house. However, houses vary with respect to amenities. For example, some have swimming pools and others don't. In order to remove any between-house variation in price per square meter which is due to the presence of a pool, I would like to compute the following model in `lme4`, where `has_pool` is 1 if the house has a swimming pool, and 0 otherwise:

```
lmer(log(rent_per_sq_meter) ~ has_pool + (1|district), data)
```

What I would like to know is, whether the BLUPs for districts can safely be interpreted as indicators of how expensive a district is, or whether there are any caveats I overlooked.
I should probably point out that the number of houses per district is not balanced.

Comment: A good aside question here is 'why'.  Why use the BLUP as an indicator of how expensive the district is rather than conduct that analysis separately (or just with descriptive statistics).  However, as a general point of knowledge it is a good question all the same.

Comment: You are right -- if it was just about swimming pools, I could conduct separate analyses. However, a lot more factors than just the presence of a pool will be going into the fixed effects. Some of these predictors are continuous, such as the size of the pool, etc. Therefore, there may not be enough data to compare specific subsets across districts. Does this make sense, or is there a simpler option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are correct. The higher the number of houses in a district, the closer you are at the district level (corrected for the effect of having a pool). The smaller the number, the closer you are the overall mean to protect you from strong overfitting.

Comment: ... and to understand the reason for this answer in more detail one good search term is 'shrinkage'.